# Parsleyjs: <input type="button"> validate and show error messages

Tags: javascript, forms, parsley.js

I have a simple form with an submit button and a button for "document creation".
Validation works with both - but the error messages only apperas when the submit button is used. I would like to show them also when the "create documents" button is klicked. Here is the code:

In my html form:

```
<input type="button" name="documents" value="<?php echo $lang_button_documents; ?>" onclick="generate_documents();">
```

In my js file:

```
// Create documents
function generate_documents() {
var form = $('#myform');
if(form.parsley('isValid') == true) {
    alert( "Function not implemented yet!" ); 
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = false;
    } else { 
        form.parsley('parsley-validate parsley-bind parsley-show-errors')
        //alert("Form data missing!");
        }
}
```

thx Alexander